# Forget to confirm your Interview Appointment

Tags: interviewing

If you got an email from the job you have been waiting desperately for, and the email says to call to confirm your attendance no later than 12pm the day before your Interview, Should you still call to confirm if it's past the time, and still show up?

Comment: Yes.  Call immediately.

Comment: No way to call the USPS. But I plan to be there bright and early. Trying to freak out and think negative. God Help Me!!

Comment: not to freak out I meant

Comment: Not to freak you out further, but be aware not confirming your attendance is not good.  They may well assume you are not coming.  If you can't contact them, how did you plan to confirm your attendance?

Comment: Well I still called and left a message of my attendance. I had my reminder note ready for this morning, but I guess with training new employee's at work, just took over a lot of my time.

Comment: I leave it ALL in GOD'S hands.

Comment: If God is handling this for you why are we wasting our time answering it?  If you put 'remembering to confirm appointments'in his hands too, you might want to find a new assistant

Comment: Better late, than never.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question can be considered in the generic case, I'll try to give a generic answer to the question:

> **Should you still call to confirm an interview time if it is after the requested confirmation date/time?**

The short answer to this is **"Yes, as soon as you realised you missed the time!"**  If you don't confirm, it is likely that they will believe you are not attending.  If at all possible, phone them, apologise for being late (do NOT give excuses!) and confirm.  If you *can't* get in contact straight away, leave a message saying the same thing and then try to phone them as soon as they are open again.

It sets a very bad precedent to miss confirmation of an interview.  It can give an impression of a lack of time management skills, or worse, a lack of respect for the interview panel.  If you find yourself in this situation, you *need to contact them as soon as possible*.  By doing so and being apologetic, you may undo the bad first impression you have perhaps created.